# How to combine tables in a (fairly complicated) BigQuery Query?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

So I have a SQL Query that pulls the IP Addresses from the Google Workspace activity logs in BigQuery and then transforms them to Geolocation data.

This all works perfectly fine. However, I also want to pull in the email address of the users as well, and I can't figure out the best way to achieve this.

The email address is available in the table `workspace-data.Logs.activity`

Example to get the email address:

```
SELECT
  DISTINCT(email)
FROM
  `workspace-data.Logs.activity`
```

The IP Address is in the same table as `email`, accessed via `ip_address`

Here is my current SQL Query:

```
WITH
  source_of_ip_addresses AS (
  SELECT
    REGEXP_REPLACE(SAFE_CONVERT_BYTES_TO_STRING(ip_address), 'xxx', '0') ip,
    COUNT(1) c
  FROM
    `workspace-data.Logs.activity`
  WHERE
    SAFE_CONVERT_BYTES_TO_STRING(ip_address) IS NOT NULL
  GROUP BY
    1 )
SELECT
  city_name,
  country_name,
  country_iso_code,
  SUM(c) c,
  ST_GEOGPOINT(AVG(longitude), AVG(latitude)) point
FROM (
  SELECT
    ip,
    city_name,
    country_name,
    country_iso_code,
    c,
    latitude,
    longitude,
    geoname_id
  FROM (
    SELECT
      *,
      NET.SAFE_IP_FROM_STRING(ip) & NET.IP_NET_MASK(4,
        mask) network_bin
    FROM
      source_of_ip_addresses,
      UNNEST(GENERATE_ARRAY(9,32)) mask
    WHERE
      BYTE_LENGTH(NET.SAFE_IP_FROM_STRING(ip)) = 4 )
  JOIN
    `fh-bigquery.geocode.201806_geolite2_city_ipv4_locs`
  USING
    (network_bin,
      mask) )
WHERE
  city_name IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY
  city_name,
  country_name,
  country_iso_code,
  geoname_id
ORDER BY
  c DESC
```

What would be the best way to incorporate the email addresses for the users alongside the transformed Geolocation data?

Currently, the query will output the following table:

| Row | city_name | country_name | country_iso_code | c | point |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Mountain View | United States | US | 50639 | POINT(-122.0574 37.4192) |
| 2 | Houston | United States | US | 24671 | POINT(-95.3454 29.9668) |
| 3 | Jacksonville | United States | US | 6717 | POINT(-81.6236 30.19675) |

But I would like for it to output:

| Row | Email | city_name | country_name | country_iso_code | c | point |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | bob@someaddress.com | Mountain View | United States | US | 165 | POINT(-122.0574 37.4192) |
| 2 | frodo@someaddress.com | Houston | United States | US | 134 | POINT(-95.3454 29.9668) |
| 3 | darth@someaddress.com | Jacksonville | United States | US | 292 | POINT(-81.6236 30.19675) |

Comment: presumably people's IP addresses will change from time to time, so dropping the ```GROUP BY``` in the ```source_of_ip_addresses``` CTE would be a place to start or ```GROUP BY``` ```email_address``` instead. If you want all IP addresses for a given email address to be on the same row then you could put the ip addresses into an array or string with something like ```ARRAY_AGG``` or ```STRING_AGG```.

Comment: Actually on second thought I think you should do ```GROUP BY email_address, ip_address``` and do ```COUNT()``` on either one (should yield same result)

Comment: I’m actually ok/hoping to get the IP addresses per person (including changes) as it would allow me to see that Bob usually access from location A, but has also accessed from Location B, C etc